# Submit several forms with one button and store variables in MySQL

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently learning forms and Ajax posting without a page refresh. I have tree forms and one submit button. I have assigned php variables to each input field that will take the value of what’s typed in. The value is echoed for each input box. Is it possible to submit all three forms at the same time? And if yes, how would I submit these values to a MySQL database after the button click?

**Ajax:**

```
function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "posting.php",
        data: { 
            "name": $("#name").val(),
            "age": $("#age").val(),
            "phone": $("#phone").val(),
            "email": $("#email").val(),
            "job": $("#job").val(),
            "hobby": $("#hobby").val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#inputResult").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo '<div id="name_input"><h2 class="lastTab">Name:</h2>' . $name . '</div>';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['age'])) {
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        echo '<div id="age_input"><h2 class="lastTab">Age:</h2>' . $age . '</div>';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        echo '<div id="phone_input"><h2 class="lastTab">Phone:</h2>' . $phone . '</div>';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        echo '<div id="email_input"><h2 class="lastTab">Email:</h2>' . $email . '</div>';
    }           

    if (isset($_POST['job'])) {
        $job = $_POST['job'];
        echo '<div id="job_input"><h2 class="lastTab">Job:</h2>' . $job . '</div>';
    }       

    if (isset($_POST['hobby'])) {
        $hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
        echo '<div id="hobby_input"><h2 class="lastTab">Hobby:</h2>' . $hobby . '</div>';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm1" name="postForm1" class="postForm">
       Name
        <input type="text" id="name" class="detail" name="name" value="" /> 
        Age
        <input type="text" id="age" class="detail" name="age" value="" />   
    </form>         
    </div>.


    <div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm2" name="postForm2" class="postForm">
        Phone Number
        <input type="text" id="phone" class="detail" name="phone" value="" />       
        Email
        <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="" /> 
    </form>     
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm3" name="postForm3" class="postForm">
        Job
        <input type="text" id="job" class="detail" name="job" value="" /> 
        Hobby
        <input type="text" id="hobby" class="detail" name="hobby" value="" />       
    </form>     
    </div>
```

Comment: Whats the problem if all the values come through?

Comment: I cant fully comprehend How can i submit the variables from all three forms at the same time

Comment: If you are getting values to the php file. Then just do your query with the values captured.

Comment: I've modified your PHP code a little bit. Hint: `if($_POST)` is not valid (turn on notices and you'll see), and `echo` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use javascript to catch the `submit` of the form or you can trigger a function that you ve created. It doesn t have to be 3 forms or even a form element for the second case to work

HTML:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm1" name="postForm1" class="postForm">
       Name
        <input type="text" id="name" class="detail" name="name" value="" /> 
        Age
        <input type="text" id="age" class="detail" name="age" value="" />   
    </form>         
    </div>.


    <div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm2" name="postForm2" class="postForm">
        Phone Number
        <input type="text" id="phone" class="detail" name="phone" value="" />       
        Email
        <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="" /> 
    </form>     
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm3" name="postForm3" class="postForm">
        Job
        <input type="text" id="job" class="detail" name="job" value="" /> 
        Hobby
        <input type="text" id="hobby" class="detail" name="hobby" value="" />
        <input type="button" value="SAVE" onclick="saveThem()" />       
    </form>     
    </div>
```

AJAX:

```
    function saveThem() {

var name = $.trim($("#name").val());
var age = $.trim($("#age").val());
var phone = $.trim($("#phone").val());
var email = $.trim($("#email").val());
var job = $.trim($("#job").val());
var hobby = $.trim($("#hobby").val());

var dataString = 'name='+name+'&age='+age+'&phone='+phone+'&email='+email+'&job='+job+'&hobby='+hobby;

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/something.php',
          data: dataString,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            if(data.response){ alert(data.message); }
            $("#inputResult").html(data);
          }
      });
    }
```

something.php

```
//Get posted variables
$name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['name']) : NULL;
$age = (isset($_POST['age'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['age']) : NULL;
$phone = (isset($_POST['phone'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['phone']) : NULL;
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['email']) : NULL;
$job = (isset($_POST['job'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['job']) : NULL;
$hobby = (isset($_POST['hobby'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['hobby']) : NULL;

//execute your query
$sql = "INSERT INTO ...";

//Return results back to ajax  
$result = array(
'response' => 1,
'message' => 'We have a success!'
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

So in conclusion is pretty much the same as using php but in the middle there is some javascript.
**Form**: create an id for each element that you want to send to your server(php)
**Js**: catch values based on element ids and send them to php
**Php**: get values, clean them, query or anything else and send results back to js

**EDIT: Using jQuery serialize()**

```
$('form').submit(function() {
 $dataString = $(this).serialize(); //This will produce the same result, based on input names

});
```

Comment: Why the datastring is like that?
I think it's better if you use "serialize()" from JQuery

Comment: Yes of course. I am just trying to explain what goes where in order for the person that asked the question to understand better.

Comment: +1 Thank you, so just to clarify i dont have to use three forms or any forms at all? i can just leave the input tags and take out the form tags?

Comment: You better use 1 <form>  if you trigger your js function on submit like: $("form").submit(){} and then like Claudio said, serialize() your data. Or you can use no form if you create your own function like saveThem().

Comment: Great explanation. I decided to take the form tags out and use the function `saveThem()`. I follow all your suggestions but now somehow the values are not being echoed in the last tab.

Comment: In my example I am using JSON as dataType. If you want to just echo your values as plain text, use "text" as dataType in your js function and echo in your php accordingly. More info http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/